# Deadlock in c++ on solaris

Tags: multithreading, solaris

Please, can anybody suggest me how to check for deadlock on Solaris with the `pstack` command?

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't really related to C++, but more the general multi-threading issue of a deadlock. 
When your program is running, get the pid and then in another xterm (or whatever you're using) you run `pstack pid` and check whether all threads are waiting for a mutex to be released. That's normally a pretty good indicator of deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

Compare pstack outputs - if they are the same, and all threads are waiting for locks then you have a deadlock.